# How do I import into the server.js of expressjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

When i try to import such as like this in server.js:

```
import SalaryService from '/components/utils/SalaryService';
```

and then want to use it like this:

```
const salaryService = new SalaryService();
res.send(salaryService.getSalaries('test'));
```

However I get the following error message when I try start my dev server:

```
C:\projects\project\server.js:10
    import SalaryService from '/components/utils/SalaryService';
    ^^^^^^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: you need to use babel or webpack to transpile your code, or run node in such a way that it understands es6 features like `import`

Answer (score 1):

Nodejs doesn't support ES6 modules syntax
If you want to use ES6 modules syntax you can use [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to run your code

Comment: What would then be the other syntax? require('/components/utils/SalaryService')?

Comment: @user1009698 yes, you can write it like this: `const SalaryService = require('/components/utils/SalaryService')`

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what module.exports in '/components/utils/SalaryService' is assigned. If it's an object with many functions (or nested objects), meaning the file SalaryService.js exports an object containing a property called 'SalaryService' you can use destructuring like so:

```
const { SalaryService } = require('/components/utils/SalaryService');
```

This is nice because you can pick a few properties from a large object cleanly:

```
const { SalaryService, SomeOtherProp } = require('/components/utils/SalaryService');
```

Otherwise if the module.exports is assigned the function or object you want directly:

```
const SalaryService = require('/components/utils/SalaryService');
```

Comment: hmm ya works, when i add a "./...".However in my salaryService i do an import and then it tells me SyntaxError: Unexpected token import. Is there a better solution or do i have to use babel?

Comment: Are you saying that it works when written require('/components/utils/SalaryService') but not require('./components/utils/SalaryService')? Is the file where you are doing the import in the directory contains the 'components' folder (relative)?

Comment: I am saying it works when I do:require('./components/utils/SalaryService') However SalaryService does import stuff and then its again not recognised